# Why NDSolve can not solve this second-order nonlinear ODE

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, nonlinear

I try to solve:

```
eq[t_] := ddf[t] + a'[t]/a[t] df[t] + 6 f[t] - 3  a[t]^2  f[t]^2
```

with

```
    f[t_] := Exp[(1/2)*(-2*(Derivative[1][a][t]/a[t]) +
 Sqrt[4*(Derivative[1][a][t]^2/a[t]^2) - 4*a[t]^2*k[t]^2])*t]

df[t_] := D[f[t], t]

ddf[t_] := D[f[t], {t,2}]
```

and:

```
k[t_] := Sqrt[(3 t Derivative[1][a][t]^2 + a[t] (Derivative[1][a][t] - 
       t (a^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t])) (-t Derivative[1][a][t]^2 + 
    a[t] (Derivative[1][a][t] + t (a^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]))]/Sqrt[
 a[t]^4 (a[t] + t Derivative[1][a][t])^2]
```

I try to solve numerically by `NDSolve` :

```
NDSolve[{eq[t]==0,a[0] == 1, a'[1] == 1, a'[1] == 1, a[1] == 1}, {a[t]}, {t, 1, 10}, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 5 ]
```

The initial conditions are so arbitrary and can be changed.

However `NDSolve` stuck and the MA code hangs. I tried to use `AsymptoticDSolveValue` but no output as well.

I know that after all the substitution the `eq[t]` is somehow complicated and has $a[t]^3$ terms, so that I use four constrains, but I hope to find a way it can be solved by MA.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you do not have `df[t]` defined. You do not have `ddf[t]` defined. Your ode seems to be second order. Yet, you are giving 4 initial/BC, and one of them is second order. This is wrong.

Comment: I added the functions definitions. Also I modified the initial conditions. Thanks @Nasser

Comment: actually your ode is 4th order. But it was hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The initial conditions are so arbitrary and can be changed.

If you make your IC's start at the start of the domain, it works. You are integrating the ode from `1` on, but you had an IC at zero. This makes life harder for `NDSolve`.

```
NDSolve[{ode, ic}, a, {t, 1, 2}, Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I changed your IC's to the following: (since you have 4th order ode)

```
ode=eq[t]==0;
ic={a[1]==1,a'[1]==1,a''[1]==1,a'''[1]==0}
```

Your `eq[t]` is too complicated, so will not copy your code here again :)

Trying to solve for larger domain than 2.2 gives

[image]

Additional changes to options for NDSolve might help with this issue.

V 14.0 on windows.